# Creating Vectors with Python

Tags: python, class

I'm creating a vector class that has one parameter being the length of a vector. The length is automatically 0 if none is entered by user. If a vector is given a length, however, each number will be set to 0. For example: `v(5)` would be `[0,0,0,0,0]` and `v()` would be `[]`.
This is the code i have thus far, but it's not quite working. Any advice?

```
class V:

    def __init__(self, length = 0):
        self.vector = [0]*length
    def __str__(self):
        print(self.vector)
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.vector)
```

Then i plug in `a = V() b = V(5)` and when i `print(a)` and `print(b)` i get an TypeError. Any advice?

Comment: What is it that isn’t working?

Comment: The basic idea you're looking for is `[0] * length`, but I'm not sure how much of the built in list behavior you want your class to share. Normally I would make this a class that has a list as member data, if I didn't just use a list directly (or numpy and its arrays).

Comment: It should be `__length` not just `length`.

Comment: You get a `TypeError` with `print(a)` because `__str__` (which is called by `print`) is supposed to return a string. Instead you printed something and returned `None`.

Answer (score 2):

I'd probably cheat and go for sub-classing `list`:

```
class V(list):
    def __init__(self, length=0):
        super(V, self).__init__([0] * length)
```

This way you get the length, repr and other goodies for free.

Answer (score 1):

```
class V:
    def __init__(self, length = 0):
        self.data = [0]*length

    def __str__(self):
        return '[{}]'.format(', '.join(str(d) for d in self.data))

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)
```

Comment: An aside: This is your 666th Python answer :)

Comment: @Jon Clements: I feel lucky ;-)

Comment: I've tried tweaking my code to the above. Is there anything you see that immediately catches your eye? I'm getting a TypeError.

Comment: @user3014014: `__str__` has to return a string. `print()` returns None, which is not a string, therefore TypeError.

Comment: @Hugh: why not just `def __str__(self): return str(self.data)`? The `__str__` function for data structures ideally should detect recursion (as that for `list` does), so it's not entirely trivial to implement it well.