# setitem and getitem -- python

Tags: python, class

I've created a python program that makes a vector. Now i want to set an item using a function`__setitem__` and`__getitem__`. So for example, if`vector = Vec()`and`vector[3] = 26`would change an empty vector to`[0, 0, 0, 26]`. I need to override the`__getitem__`and`__setitem__` I've listed the code below, but i'm having troubles with the get and set functions. Any advice?

```
class Vec:
    def __init__(self, length = 0):
        self.vector = [0]*length

    def __str__(self):
        return '[{}]'.format(', '.join(str(i) for i in self.vector))
        #This formats the output according to the homework.
        #Adds '[' and ']' and commas between each 0

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.vector)

    def extend(self, newLen):
        self.vector.append([0]*newLen)
        return (', '.join(str(j) for j in self.vector))

    def __setitem__(self, key, item):
        self.vector[key] = item

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.vector[key]
```

Comment: what troubles are you having exactly?

Comment: I'm not able to change keys and items that are in my vector as i thought i should be able to. Do you see anything?

Comment: @user3014014 I take it this is a learning exercise, and you can't just inherit from `list` as shown in [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20338675/creating-vectors-with-python) ?

Comment: Tip for the future:  As shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9061024/2555451), `str.join` runs better with a list comprehension than it does with a generator expression.

Comment: Even if this is a learning exercise - I'm puzzled as to what you're supposed to be learning... At the moment all it's accounting to is duplicating `list`s interface and explicitly calling its implementation of methods...

Comment: Please explain better than "am not able", it would be very useful to see a complete example and a stacktrace such as:  

    >>> v = Vec()
    >>> v[3] = 26

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
        v[3] = 26
      File "C:\Users\S\Desktop\test.py", line 18, in __setitem__
        self.vector[key] = item
    IndexError: list assignment index out of range
    >>>

Comment: I'm entering v = Vec() >>> v[3] = 26. I want my output to read [0, 0, 0, 26], but it gives me an IndexError.

Answer (score 12):

You have several problems:

1. `extend` is appending essentially a new vector to the end of the original, rather than increasing the length of the original. It's not clear that it needs to return a string representation of the modified vector (unless it's just for debugging purposes).

   ```
   def extend(self, newlength):
       # Assume newlength is greater than the old
       self.vector.extend([0] * (newlength - len(self)))
   ```
2. `__setitem__` needs to call `extend` if the key is too large.

   ```
   def __setitem__(self, key, item):
       if key >= len(self):
           self.vector.extend(key+1)
       self.vector[key] = item
   ```
3. `__getitem__` needs to access the underlying list, not use an undefined attribute

   ```
   def __getitem__(self, key):
       # It's probably better to catch any IndexError to at least provide
       # a class-specific exception
       return self.vector[key]
   ```

Answer (score 6):

The problem is the vector you created has no length because of the default value given the `length` keyword argument in the `__init__()` method definition. Try this:

```
vector = Vec(4)
vector[3] = 26
print vector  # --> [0, 0, 0, 26]
```

Answer (score 2):

It would be easier in `__str__` if you do this

```
return str(self.vector)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to adapt your `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` to delegate to the underlying list:

```
def __setitem__(self, key, item):
    self.vector[key] = item 
    # return doesn't make sense here

def __getitem__(self, key):
    # not sure what self.__key is ? Let's return value from index in `self.vector` instead
    return self.vector[key]
```