# What does self[identifier] = some_value do in this code?

Tags: python

I was just trying to learn K-ary tree implementation in Python and came across this link:
http://www.quesucede.com/page/show/id/python-3-tree-implementation

In the tree.py file, there is a section of code like this:

```
class Tree:

    def __init__(self):
        self.__nodes = {}

    @property
    def nodes(self):
        return self.__nodes

    def add_node(self, identifier, parent=None):
        node = Node(identifier)
        self[identifier] = node

        if parent is not None:
            self[parent].add_child(identifier)

        return node

    # ... ...

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.__nodes[key]

    def __setitem__(self, key, item):
        self.__nodes[key] = item
```

What is `self[identifier]`? Is it a list? This is really confusing.
Can someone explain and/or point me to some documentation of using self as a list?

Comment: Was there a `__getitem__` defined in this class? We can't answer your question without seeing what the `__getitem__` does

Comment: Also `__setitem__`, which is invoked for item assignment instead of item retrieval.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [setitem and getitem -- python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20356401/setitem-and-getitem-python)

Comment: Updated full code. Thanks mod

Comment: `self` is just a Tree, `self.__nodes` is a dictionary. `self['value']` uses that `__getitem__`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the full example code, this is the important bit:

```
def __getitem__(self, key):
    return self.__nodes[key]

def __setitem__(self, key, item):
    self.__nodes[key] = item
```

These two 'magic methods', `__getitem__` and `__setitem__`, allow the class to be accessed like a list or dictionary would be, using the `foo[key]` syntax.

So, in your case, if `foo` was a `Tree` instance, `foo["a"] = "b"` would execute `__setitem__` with `key` as `"a"` and `item` as `"b"`, consequently mapping `key` to `item` in the `self.__nodes` dictionary.

Comment: Okaayy...had never worked with Objects as dictionary in that way so overlooked that part. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

They are using the `__getitem__` magic method. This method is used in a class to allow its instances to use [] (indexer) operators for list indexing, dictionary lookups, or accessing ranges of values.

In the fallowing sample, we have a list with some extra functionality like head and tail. Example taken from [here](http://www.rafekettler.com/magicmethods.html):

```
class FunctionalList:
    '''A class wrapping a list with some extra functional magic, like head,
    tail, init, last, drop, and take.'''

    def __init__(self, values=None):
        if values is None:
            self.values = []
        else:
            self.values = values

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.values)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        # if key is of invalid type or value, the list values will raise the error
        return self.values[key]

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self.values[key] = value

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        del self.values[key]

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.values)

    def __reversed__(self):
        return FunctionalList(reversed(self.values))

    def append(self, value):
        self.values.append(value)
    def head(self):
        # get the first element
        return self.values[0]
    def tail(self):
        # get all elements after the first
        return self.values[1:]
    def init(self):
        # get elements up to the last
        return self.values[:-1]
    def last(self):
        # get last element
        return self.values[-1]
    def drop(self, n):
        # get all elements except first n
        return self.values[n:]
    def take(self, n):
        # get first n elements
        return self.values[:n]
```